# Dojo Nested Widgets - Cannot use dom.byId or query

Tags: dojo, widget, nested

I have two custom widgets created with dojo, `widgetA` and `widgetB`.

Loading `widgetB` from within `widgetA` (`widgetA` contains `widgetB`), then `dom.byID("id")` or `query("#id")` returns nothing on the child widget.

Same happens when loading `widgetB` from `widget A.` Note, that when instantiating each widget separately (not nested), both functions work as expected.

Is this a dojo problem?

in postCreate:

```
  var button = domConstruct.create("button", { innerHTML: "my button", id: "btnSelect" }, "placeholder");
```

when nesting the widgets it cannot find the "`placeholder`" element.

The html

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

Comment: I'm sure that you will get more help if you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or something similar. It's hard to imagine your situation from this description.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good practice to use ID's in widgets and that you can directly access DOM nodes from widgetA to widgetB without providing a decend API in widgetB.

Your ID's should be removed (what are you going to do if you use the widget twice on a page?) and use attach points in stead.

if you define the following HTML in your first widget:

```html
<div data-dojo-attach-point="placeholderNode"></div>
```

Then you can access your DOM node from the same widget using `this.placeholderNode`. You could also access it from the other widget by referencing to it using `myOtherWidget.placeholderNode`.

But like @xyu said, please provide a full example of how you're creating widgetB from widgetA.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't find the placeholder div is because it has not been added to the dom during the postCreate function. If you try to create the button during the startup function it should work because at that point the widget's html has been added to the dom.

However, I would not recommend doing this. Use attachPoints instead of ID's, as Dimitri suggested.

Comment: Hi, I cannot add attach point, because I am creating various div elements programmatically and access them later in the code. To prevent having duplicate ids I am generating a guid for each new widget and attach it to the end of each div element (i.e. placeholderXXXX)

Comment: You really need to edit your question to include more information. You can move your button creation code to the startup function or you can keep a reference to your placeholder div when you create it. Without more information it is difficult to say what the best way to do it is.